# A simpler way to find the source of a query?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

How do you figure out what workbook a query in Excel points to?

After much back and forth I managed to come up with the following sub, which produces a string I can extract the name and path of the workbook from, but I feel there ought to be a simpler way to find this info? Am I missing something.

The sub I've produced is

```
Sub test()
    Dim wbq As WorkbookQuery

    For Each wbq In ThisWorkbook.Queries
        Debug.Print wbq.Formula
    Next wbq
End Sub
```

which prints something like

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("[what I want]"), null, true),
    Sheet2 = Source{[Name="Sheet1"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Sheet2,{"Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18"}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Removed Columns",4),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Promoted Headers", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null})))
in
    #"Removed Blank Rows"
```

Comment: My understanding is there is no simpler way than what you've shown. The query is written in `M`/Power Query Formula language -- which, to my knowledge, can't be evaluated, or interfaced with, in VBA. I think the best you can do is to get the `WorkbookQuery.Formula` (as you're currently doing) and resort to string matching to try to extract the path being passed. This is fine when the path is hard coded within the call to `Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("..."))` (as in your example), but harder if indirection is involved and the function is ...

Comment: ... being passed an identifier/variable -- as you end up trying to re-create parts of the language's evaluation engine. But maybe someone else can tell you differently.

Comment: @chillin Thanks - I guess I'll just work with that then. Do you think you can make your comments into an answer, and I'll mark this as solved?

Comment: Sure, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is there is no simpler way than what you've shown. The query is written in `M`/Power Query Formula language -- which, to my knowledge, can't be evaluated, or interfaced with, in VBA.

I think the best you can do is to get the `WorkbookQuery.Formula` (as you're currently doing) and resort to string matching to try to extract the path being passed.

This is fine when the path is hard coded within the call to `Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("..."))` (as in your example), but harder if indirection is involved and the function is being passed an identifier/variable -- as you end up trying to re-create parts of the language's evaluation engine.

But maybe someone else can tell you differently.